# Update dynamic element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery `.on()` to get a click event on a dynamic element, such as follows:

```
$("body").on("click", "#books tr", function() {
    ....
    // generates a button
    $("#result").append("<button class='upload'>Upload</button>"+
                        "<input type='file' class='hidden'><span></span>");
});
```

Then i create another `.on()` event which detects a click on the generated button, using:

```
$("body").on("click", ".upload", function() {
    // which alters the element previously created by the .on() even before.
    var input = $(this).next("input");

    $(input).click();

    var upload = $(input).val();
    $(input).next("span").html(upload);
});
```

While i am trying to update the `html` in the span tag, the updating process takes place only once I press the `.upload()` button twice.

Selecting an item in the `input` tag for the first time does not update the the `span` which it should. Pressing the button again updates the tag.

Comment: You should create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo for it. Not only to get better answers but also having yourself looking at this out of your current document. It helps me a lot trying to do a simple demo only concentrating on the failing parts

Comment: @Namit You may want to accept one of the answers as the correct one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the **`jquery does not wait for you to finish the file selection here`**

So i added a **`onChange method of your input type file`**

```
$('body').on("change", "#hidden", function (){
    var upload = $(this).val();
    $(this).next("span").html(upload);
});
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/DMC5b/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 on click events. The first one creates the first button and the second one takes care of the upload. Take off the on click event for the first, instead you could create it when the document is ready. This way the upload button will already be there and you'll only need to click once.

Here is what I'd do:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { // <-- this is what I replaced!
    // generates a button
    $("#result").append("<button class='upload'>Upload</button>" +
        "<input type='file' class='hidden'><span></span>");
});

$("body").on("click", ".upload", function () {
    // which alters the element previously created by the .on() even before.
    var input = $(this).next("input");

    $(input).click();

    var upload = $(input).val();
    $(input).next("span").html(upload);
});
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3cnCB/)